# Github app to update multiple repositories

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, git-tag

I want to update multiple repositories with files based on a template repository. Is there any app that lets me do it on git?

Comment: I used the scheduled workflow to copy over the files from the template repository.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless your template repository can be considered a subfolder of your other repositories.

In that case, said other repositories can declare the template one as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), and any `git submodule update --remote` in any of your other repositories would update the template folder as well.